# <s:graphicImage> not getting .bmp file in JSF

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, seam

while going to upload an image like ".jpg/.jpeg" , ".png" file <s:graphicImage> tag is taking  these file type but it is not taking ".bmp" type file. can anyone help guide to resolve this issue?

```
private boolean chkImageUpload(){
    log.info("chkImageUpload started");
    boolean chk = false;
    long fileSize = 0;
    String contentType = null;
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {
        if(object.getTempPhotoGraph() != null){
            contentType = object.getInefFileType();
            if (!((contentType.contains("jpeg"))||(contentType.contains("jpg"))||(contentType.contains("gif"))||(contentType.contains("tiff"))||(contentType.contains("bmp")))){
                facesMessages.add("JPG/JPEG/GIF/TIFF/BMP type of images are allowed");
                return chk;
            }                   
        }   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e);
    }
    log.info("chkImageUpload ended");
    return chk;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bug an isuue is logged here  [Bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBPAPP-5766?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel). Support for BMP file is not available.

You can solve it by another way Try below code.

```
<h:graphicImage> instead of <s:graphicImage>.
```

Comment: Thanks I also tried this but it is giving some error because I want to display the image from backend bean getter. <h:graphicImage> takes the  path of file but <s:graphicImage> takes InputStream or byte[].

Comment: Yes you are true <h> tag does not support dynamic image.